# Can I use type cast operator for 2 similar looking classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

Suppose I have the following 2 classes. How do I use type conversion to achieve an effect as described below? What I want is:
I'm returning this + 1 and this - 1 because my 2 classes are always contiguous in memory.

```
right *r = new right ();
left* l = (left*)r;

class left : public top {
    int b;

    operator right * () {
        return this + 1;
    }
};

class right : public top {
    int c;

    operator left * () {
        return this - 1;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no safe way to convert an pointer of type `right*` to a pointer of type `left*` or vice-versa. You must do one of two things:

1. Use a pointer of type `top*` instead. It is safe to convert either a `left*` or a `right*` to a `top*`.
2. Use a template to perform whatever operation you want to perform on either a `left*` or a `right*` (assuming they "look similar" enough that the template code will work on either one).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tyler.

So as a followup, I would like to ask:

Suppose I have a 
class bottom : public left, public right {}; (classic diamond problem)

and now I do 
left *l = left* (bottom);
right *r = right* (bottom);

How does it happen that the right points properly with offset ? I was trying to implement this for my own understanding.

Comment: @shrinidhisondur, did you mean for `l` and `r` to be pointers in that comment?  As it is, you're just making copies.

Comment: @shrinidhisondur How the class layout is managed is compiler-dependent. The only guarantee is that casting from `bottom*` to either `left*` or `right*` is safe, and does what you expect. (Also, your `bottom` object will have two copies of anything defined in `top`, one for each parent.) What you're asking now is essentially this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321062/object-layout-in-case-of-virtual-functions-and-multiple-inheritance (some answers for gcc there)

Comment: Alright. Thanks. I did mean them as pointers. Thanks for the response again.