# memory layout of a multiple-inherited object in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, multiple-inheritance

```
class B1 {
    virtual void f1();
    int int_in_b1;
};
class B2 {
    virtual void f2();
    int int_in_b2;
};
class D: B1, B2 {
    int int_in_d;
    void f1();
    void f2();
};
class D1: B1, B2 {
    int int_in_d;
    virtual void f1();
    virtual void f2();
};
```

Based on this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), the memory layout for an object `d` of class `D` is like this:

```
d:
  +0: pointer to virtual method table of D (for B1)
  +4: value of int_in_b1
  +8: pointer to virtual method table of D (for B2)
 +12: value of int_in_b2
 +16: value of int_in_d

virtual method table of D (for B1):
  +0: D::f1()  // B1::f1() is overridden by D::f1()

virtual method table of D (for B2):
  +0: D::f2()   // B2::f2() is overridden by D::f2()
```

What about an object of class `D1`? In class `D1`, the members `f1` and `f2` are both declared as `virtual`!

Comment: The implementation of dynamic polymorphism is an implementation detail, not a fact of C++ itself. So, specify which ABI you are talking about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object layout in case of virtual functions and multiple inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321062/object-layout-in-case-of-virtual-functions-and-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: @jxh, typos. It should be B1 and B2

Comment: Why B1::f1() is not overridden in D?

Comment: @newbie: Cut and paste error from wikipedia article, which was illustrating what happens if you do not override. I fixed the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `virtual` is redundant in `D1`.

From C++11, §10.3¶2:

> If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in a class `Derived`, derived directly or indirectly from `Base`, a member function `vf` with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5), cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or absence of same) as `Base::vf` is declared, **then `Derived::vf` is also virtual (whether or not it is so declared)** and it overrides<sup>111</sup> `Base::vf`.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>111) A function with the same name but a different parameter list (Clause 13) as a virtual function is not necessarily virtual and does not override. The use of the `virtual` specifier in the declaration of an overriding function is legal but redundant (has empty semantics). Access control (Clause 11) is not considered in determining overriding.</sub>

Thus, the memory layout (which is what the question seems to be about) is the same for `D` and `D1`. Obviously, different types will have different virtual tables.

Answer (score 1):

`f1()` and `f2()` are *virtual* in `D` too. If a function is declared *virtual*, it remains *virtual* in any class that inherits.

So, classes `D` and `D1` almost do not differ inside (but, obviously, are different types), but both of them give implementations of `f1` and `f2`, and their *virtual tables* will differ, as virtual table for `D` will point to `D`'s implementations, and the same for `D1`.

```
vtable for D:
    f1: D::f1
    f2: D::f2

vtavle for D1:
    f1: D1::f1
    f2: D1::f2
```

Comment: But the contents of the Virtual Method Table will surely differ…

Comment: @JonasWielicki, this is exactly what I want to ask. what's the difference in the virtual method table?

Comment: It seems that they are the same based on your update.

Comment: @Daniel each of `D` and `D1` provide their own implementations to `f1` and `f2`. Virtual tables will point to implementations from `D` or `D1` respectively.

Comment: @FihopZz no, they are not.